# Headrush (multi effects) into Mesa Boogie Mark V 35 Amp - Issue!

Tags: guitar, amplifiers, guitar-effects, effects-pedal, effects

I have a Mesa Boogie Mark V 35 practice amp, and I love the natural tone of this amp on the clean and red channels. It is fantastic to play it 'straight'/'raw' without any effects.

However I have a Headrush multi-effects guitar pedal board, which I want to use for additional effects (reverb, delay, echo, wah, etc etc).

I do not want to use the Headrush's inbuilt amp or cab simulators all the time (90% of the time, I would rather use my real amp for this - and just keep the multi-FX board, to simply using just the effects).

However, when I plug the Headrush into the FX loop at the back of the Mesa, it bypasses all the actual Mesa channels and their tones.

When I plug the Headrush into the front of the Mesa (through the input jack), it totally cancels all the overdrive/distortion from the Mesa and basically sounds clean only, with no tone control through the Mesa.

I feel like I've tried everything, amp I missing something here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't have this equipment, but I find the "plug to the guitar input" "cancelling distortion odd." It may just be that the output is too low to drive the amp to distort though. I see they recommend a "4-cable method" ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiZwm_DpDe4&t=1s ) where the fx send goes to the main input of the amp, amp send goes to FX return; the L mon out goes to amp return. You'd then set up your board so that some are pre-pre-amp and other post-pre-amp (FX loop). Also check your amp/line out switch(es) and also check the GUI setup for similar.